# Using OpenId with Bottle

Tags: python, python-3.x, openid, bottle, google-openid

So i'm creating a blog engine in python with bottle. I would like to be able to have it create and run it's own login system and use OpenId.

Can I use OpenId with bottle? If so how?
*Bonus brownie points if you can tell me how to request information from the user profile through this.*

Are there any other alternatives that works with Google?

Do you have any Tips or guides for making a secure login system?

BTW: I use python 3

Edit: I have decided to just move to Flask it has openid and heaps more.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any turnkey solution for this, but you might want to check out this simple auth class for bottle: https://github.com/bbrodriges/bottlepy-user-auth, which shows an example how to bind together your bottle webapp and your user database. 
So by using this as a base and a implementing a wrapper class on the top of the python-openid library, and use it as the 'db' class in the linked auth class. You can also extend this class to handle further profile infos you need.